# what would I use for a meteor package manager

Tags: meteor

I understand meteor has their own package manager under the covers (that way `meteor deploy` works to include the packages) but I'm looking for a package manager for meteor.  By package manager, i'm looking for like bundler/gemfile (ruby) or maven/pom file (java).

Again I understand the meteor install works fine, but I want to define my own "private" packages as well as have a file to put the package declarations in so when I go to update I can do it easily.

I saw meteorite, but I also read where as of meteor 0.9.0 it is no longer needed.

Thanks!

EDIT:

so for example, in ruby you have the bundler gem which has a gemfile.  in the gemfile you put

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
gem '<gem_name>','<gem_version>' 
gem '<gem_name>','<gem_version>'
```

and anytime you want to install all the dependencies on a new machine you just run `bundle install` and it installs the dependencies into the new machine.

I want to do something similar in meteor.  example: I have a meteor project that takes the karma and angular-meteor packages (as well as a couple private packages in a bitbucket repo).

so in a gemfile, it would look something like this

```
source 'http://<atmosphere_url>'
package 'uringo:angular','0.8.8'
package 'sanjo:karma','1.5.1'

source 'https://<my_bit_bucket_repo'>'
package 'name:package1','0.0.1'
package 'name:package2','0.0.1'
```

and then I just need the command to run the package manager to install the different packages.

Comment: If your need is to have private packages, meaning packages not on GitHub or Atmosphere, then the default package manager will work just fine. The package declaration file is `/.meteor/packages`. Did I get your question and needs right?

Comment: @Kyll mostly... I need to find documentation on what file I need to add there, syntax, how to "execute" the package manager install, etc.

Comment: I still don't understand. The syntax of the `packages` file is dead simple: One package name per line. You don't put files in the `packages` file but package names (from Atmosphere or your local `/packages` folder. What package manager installation? Meteor manages packages on its own. Maybe explaining your exact need would help.

Comment: @Kyll see edit for a clearer explanation of what I'm trying to do

Comment: I'm sorry, but I still don't see why you're having troubles. The default behaviour of the last versions of Meteor is exactly that. In your case, in the `.meteor/packages` file you would have `uringo:angular@0.8.8 \n sanjo:karma@1.5.1` and when you run `meteor` it automatically downloads all the packages and dependencies for you.

Comment: @Kyll where is documentation on this and how do you do different sources like my bitBucket account?  this has to be the least documented feature on http://docs.meteor.com/#/basic/packages

Comment: On the top left of the docs page you have a list, select "Full doc". On it you will find data about [package.js](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/packagejs) which is quite an ugly pack of stuff to know about creating packages. Here's [some more stuff about versionning](https://meteorhacks.com/meteor-packaging-system-understanding-versioning) on meteorhacks. I'm writing an answer to introduce quickly the packages system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like I have to keep packages with the code.  So in the top level directory, there's the package folder and all my internal packages for the project will need to live there.  Then I just modify the .meteor/project file to include which packages I want in that build.  Then when I launch `meteor` then even though there are many packages in my /packages folder, only the packages in the .meteor/project file will be included.

`In addition to the packages in the official Meteor release being used by your app, meteor list and meteor add also search the packages directory at the top of your app. You can also use the packages directory to break your app into subpackages for your convenience, or to test packages that you might want to publish. See Writing Packages.` -- http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/usingpackages

so this means just because the package is included in the /packages directory within the project, doesn't mean the project is actually 'using' the package.